# Get records except soft-deleted from all related table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8. Here I have two table `category` and `post` which are related to each other and both include `softdelete`.

When I softdelete record from category table, and tries to search record, using any keywords and if that keywords is found in post table but its category is softdeleted then error occurs.

I am writing the code as below. And also try differently but no success.

**Code use for searching:**

```
$posts = Post::with(['category:id,name,slug'])
    ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
    ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
    ->get();
```

From this code I am getting record of post which belongs to category that is softdeleted, so it returns null category and cause the error Missing parameter Category. But How can I change above code so that it doesn't return post which category is softdeleted.

**Model: Post.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**Model: Category.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Post::class, 'category_id');
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/{category:slug}/{pSlug}/{id}', [MasterPostController::class, 'showPost'])->name('post.detail');
```

**Error:**

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: post.detail] [URI: {category}/{pSlug}/{id}] [Missing parameter: category]. (View: L:\Links\getalow\resources\views\search-post.blade.php)
```

I also use `->has('category')` but not working

Comment: Error indicates that you are calling `post.detail` route (perhaps while loading view) without passing the required `category` parameter. Including posts that belong to a deleted category is, in one sense, another story.

Comment: Yes, and I have category model in route, but Its happning because I get record from above code with category null, I wan't to get record which are not softdeleted from related table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes In this case you will get category as null, and when it is passed in route you will get that error. So to solve this problem you have to filter your post after getting it you can do it in two ways.

**Method 1:**

After receiving the post, while on loop, check for if category is null -> omit that data.

**Method 2:**

Improving your code by using whereNotNull('category'). Below is the code

```
$posts = Post::with(['category:id,name,slug'])
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
        ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
        ->get()->whereNotNull('category');
```